# With Bash, how to print the whole lines of a .txt file which contain, in their first section, a specific string?

Tags: string, bash, awk

So far, I used `grep` for these kind of questions, but here, I think it can't be use. Indeed, I want a match **in the first section** of each line, and then print the whole line.

I wrote something like that:

`cat file.txt | cut -d " " -f1 | grep root`

But of course, this command does not print the whole line, but only the first section of each line that contains "root". I've heard of `awk` command, but even with the manual, I do not understand how to reach my goal.

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `awk` should do it:

```
awk '$1 ~ /root/' file.txt
```

Comment: Ok, so the `$1` refers to the first part of the line, but what is the purpose of the `~` ?

Comment: It compares the first field `$1` to the given regex `/root/`. From manual: `‘~’ and ‘!~’ perform regular expression comparisons.` -- refer to [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Usage) for more information.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot for your quick answer, I spent way too much time trying to figure that out :)